# Testing iOS app on jailbroken device (iphone 3G)

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to test my app on my device (Jailbroken), using Jailcoder and so on, but I always get the same error:

```
  dyld: Symbol not found: _kSecCFErrorArchitecture
  Referenced from: /usr/bin/codesign
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
 in /usr/bin/codesign
/Users/Jasko/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PROBA_joystick-chspwbfjpsxrxlewruowyfcsrdvs/ArchiveIntermediates/PROBA joystick/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/PROBA joystick.build/Release-iphoneos/PROBA joystick.build/Script-50524F424C454D533F.sh: line 6: 15003 Trace/BPT trap          codesign -f -s "iPhone Developer" --entitlements "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${WRAPPER_NAME}/${PROJECT_NAME}.xcent" "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${WRAPPER_NAME}/"
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 133
```

I've done it once successfully (with another application), and I'm comparing build settings of these two projects, and i cant find the difference, but it wont compile...

Comment: "but I always get the same error:" - Where? When?

Comment: when building app for testing or running with my iphone chosen

Comment: Is the error appearing in Xcode? Does your app throw it when trying to launch it?

Comment: yes, it's appearing in Xcode. It's running fine on iphone 4.2 simulator, but I cant build it for my device. I'm using xcode 4.0 on mac os snow leopard

Answer (score 0):

If the methods are added via a category, you may need to add one or both of these in your target's build settings under other linker flags `-ObjC` or `-all_load`